# Unable to reconnect container created by "Clone Repository in Container Volume" easily?

Tags: docker, visual-studio-code, vscode-devcontainer

I started with a blank new window and use the command `Remote-Containers: Clone Repository in Container Volume` to clone a git hub repo that I wanted to work with. This spawned a container in which I made some changes. However, after I close the window, it seems there's no way for me to re-open that container easily in VS Code. I had to manually restart that container in the shell and use the command `Remote-Containers: Attach to Running Container` to continue my development. What I'm missing here? or this is what it is?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a slightly easier way would be to use the Docker extension. You can right-click on a container and select "Attach Visual Studio Code".

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rzSZx.png)